# AWS API Gateway remove response headers

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway

I have created an API using AWS api gateway which contains a mock endpoint `/test`.

In my response, I get the headers `x-amzn-RequestId` and `x-amz-apigw-id`. In case of an error, e.g. using a non existing endpoint `/test2`, I also get the `x-amazn-ErrorType` header.

I don't want these aws headers to be in my api response. How can these be removed?

Comment: There are workarounds to eliminate these, but others may appear as a side effect.  Why do you want these removed?

Comment: Michael do you have some documentation for this please?  Our API consumer has specified what headers they expect, so we need a way to remove these spurious x-amzn headers please.

Comment: Have added solution, let me know if you need any more info

Comment: I have the same problem. In our API program, we don't necessarily want to expose the underlying infra provider. Adds more info than is necessary, informs potential attack vectors.

Answer (score 4):

Add CloudFront in front of your API Gateway. Then add a [Lambda@Edge function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html) for either origin response or viewer response to remove these attributes from the array.

Comment: Is this still the best/only way to accomplish this?

Comment: I believe CloudFront is still the way to go, but would recommend using a Response Header Policy instead of invoking a Lambda@Edge. A policy doesn't need maintenance over time as lambda runtimes get deprecated, and is likely to be faster. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/creating-response-headers-policies.html